# Phonegap/iOS - how to push childviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, pushviewcontroller

I'm able to implement the concept of childviewcontroller in my PhoneGap project. 
Now when I click on any link of my app, that opens in childviewcontroller successfully.

Here is a line that opens the page in clildbrowser

```
[super.viewController presentModalViewController:childBrowser
animated:YES ];
```

Now I want to open childBrowser as a pushViewController. Currently it comes from bottom to top but i want this to open from left to right.

Is there any way? Replacing `presentModalViewController` to `pushViewController` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presentModalViewController and pushViewController ar every different in concept.
If you just need to change the animation, you might want to do something like this:

```
childBrowser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
//childBrowser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
//childBrowser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
//childBrowser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[super.viewController presentModalViewController:modalViewController
                                           animated:YES];
```

or simply use traditional animations (code needs adapting):

```
UIViewController *controller = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIViewAnimationTransition trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: trans forView: [self window] cache: YES];
[navController presentModalViewController: controller animated: NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```